# rails rspec access other tables when testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm pretty new to rails and find myself having some problems with understanding the relation between my database tables (i guess?).

My problem is the following:

I've got a Users table, containing information about users including their email addresses and another table containing "games" i'd like to manage those players played.
When players want to submit their games, they have to specify the users participating in the game by their email addresses. I'd like to validate whether or not those players really exist.

My Game model:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :caster1, :caster2, :faction1, :faction2, :player1, :player2, :points, :won

  before_save { |game| player1 = player1.downcase }
  before_save { |game| player2 = player2.downcase }

  validate :existence_of_both_players

  ...
  (some more validations)
  ...

  private
    def existence_of_both_players
        User.exists?(:email => :player1.downcase) && User.exists?(:email => :player2.downcase)
    end
end
```

My test case is the following:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Game do

  before do
    @game = Game.new( player1:  "foobar@example.com",
                      faction1: "Some faction",
                      caster1:  "Some caster",
                      player2:  "bazbaz@example.com",
                      faction2: "Some other faction",
                      caster2:  "Some other caster",
                      points:   35,
                      won:      true)
  end

  ...
  (some other specs)
  ...

  describe "saving a game" do
    let(:player1) { User.create(name:                   "Example1", 
                                email:                  "example1@foo.bar",
                                password:               "foobar",
                                password_confirmation:  "foobar") }
    let(:player2) { User.create(name:                   "Example2", 
                                email:                  "example2@foo.bar",
                                password:               "foobar",
                                password_confirmation:  "foobar") }

    describe "with invalid players" do

      describe "when both players do not exist" do
        before { @game.player1 = @game.player2 = "some_wrong_user@example.com" }
        it { should_not be_valid }
      end

      describe "when player1 does not exist" do
        before { @game.player2 = player2 }
        it { should_not be_valid }
      end

      describe "when player2 does not exist" do
        before { @game.player1 = player1 }
        it { should_not be_valid }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid players" do
      before do 
        @game.player1 = player1
        @game.player2 = player2
      end

      it { should be_valid }
    end
  end
end
```

(Sorry for the mass of code, I just thought it would help).

My test are failing, and I'm pretty sure it's obvious why, sadly not for me.

```
Failures:

  1) Game saving a game with invalid players when both players do not exist 
     Failure/Error: it { should_not be_valid }
       expected valid? to return false, got true
     # ./spec/models/game_spec.rb:108:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
...
```

I really can not figure out, why this is not working. I read the rails book and watched several screencasts, but none of them explains my problem properly.

Since this is my first post on stackoverflow, please let me know, if this post is too verbose. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're setting the players on the Game model to just the email address, rather than using an association?

Comment: Not particularly. The main reason is, that I don't really know how to work with an association because I'm regularly not much of a database guy. My idea was, that it's the easiest for the user to remember and fill in someones email address. It's my first time working with them really. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: This is one of the better beginner rails questions already, usually they are pretty bad.

Comment: `player1 = ` won't work, replace with: `self.player1 = `

Comment: @user1685739 I would suggest either adding the caster and faction to the User, or creating an intermediary model (GamePlayer?) with these values that has_one :user, then your game has_many Users/GamePlayers, and also has_one :winner. Sorry, it's a little bit complex, but if you set these up as associations, you'll make your life easier further down the road since you can more easily refer to a game's players, and a user's games. You can validate the email address when the user enters it just the same.

Comment: Seems pretty complicated at first sight :) Thanks for your advice, I'll try to work it out and see, if this will fit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

A custom validator method should call errors.add to signal an error. So in your case something like:

```
    def existence_of_both_players
      player_one_exists = User.find_by_email :player1.downcase
      player_two_exists = User.find_by_email :player2.downcase
      unless player_one_exists and player_two_exists
          errors.add :game, "both players need to exist"
      end
    end
```

Read more in the guide for [ActiveRecord Validations and Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods).

Comment: according to [source code](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/exists%3F/class), `exists` needs an `id`

Comment: true that - changing to find_by_email

Comment: thanks a lot, this piece of code fixed one of the problems. Thanks for the link too, always nice to have more learning resources.